# how to use flex css for a minimum width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a Calendar application and I want to select an interval of months and display them.
When I select max 3 months this is how it looks like

[image]

... and when I want to display more, looks like that.

[image]

I am using css flex and with it I want to have a max width for my browser in order to display them nicely. Do I need an algorithm or?

This is my html

```
<div class="container-calendar1">
    <ca-month-calendar *ngFor="let selectedMonth of selectedMonths" [month]="selectedMonth"> 
    </ca-month-calendar>

  <ca-month-calendar>
  </ca-month-calendar>
</div>
```

and my css file

```
.container-calendar1{
    display: flex;
    flex: 2;
}

month-calendar {
    margin:20px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `flex-wrap: wrap;` and set `width:` whatever you want**

See example:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex-wrap: wrap` will wrap your flex items onto multiple lines.

```css
.container-calendar1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 2;
}

.month-calendar {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-calendar1">
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
  <div class="month-calendar">
    Calendar
  </div>
</div>
```